# Rails server is not starting on MAC M2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, macos-ventura, ruby-3.1

I am trying to run a rails app on my Mac M2 but it's always freezes during the puma boot process.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.7.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
```

This app runs fine on my linux machine. The app uses postgres as db and webpacker for handling assets. I tried debugging by using binding.pry in application.rb, to see if everything is being loaded properly and everything's fine there. It loads the initializers also. After that for some reason the boot up process hangs. At last I have to forcefully kill the process.

Also it's the same with all rails process. eg: rails c also freezes up and never starts. Ruby version is 3.1.2

Please help me out here.

Comment: Copy paste from your terminal into your question, properly formatted. Don't link screenshots because: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 (covered in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Update Dependencies: Make sure you have the latest versions of Rails, Puma, Postgres, and other dependencies specified in your Gemfile. You can update your Gemfile with the desired versions and run bundle update to update the dependencies.

Check Postgres Connection: Verify that your Postgres database is running and accessible from your Rails app. Ensure that the database configuration in config/database.yml is correctly set up to connect to your Postgres instance.

Comment: 1. Verified postgres connection. Even if there was some issue, rails would have thrown error.
2. Not sure about all the gems but most of them are updated. Also Rails and Puma are almost on their latest versions

Answer (score 0):

Punt on the whole thing.  Install docker and do all your work in containers.  Obviously this stuff works for others.  With docker you know exactly what you're using and all the dependencies.  If it works for anyone it'll work for you.

Comment: Ya, with docker it will work. I was just curious why this issue was happening. Wanted to see if anyone else has faced this issue